# gettinf error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, lda

```
def generateTopics(corpus, dictionary):
    # Build LDA model using the above corpus
    lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=50)
    corpus_lda = lda[corpus]

    # Group topics with similar words together.
    tops = set(lda.show_topics(50))
    top_clusters = []
    for l in tops:
        top = []
    for t in l.split(" + "):
        top.append((t.split("*")[0], t.split("*")[1]))
    top_clusters.append(top)
```

i am trying to get topics using lda.but in this code when i try to group topics with similar words together i get this error.
    for t in l.split(" + "):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only split strings.

Try

```
str(l).split(" + ")
```

Otherwise, don't use a tuple.